# Best way to implement Angular cross field validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to figure out the best way to implement cross field validation in Angular.

For example, I have a select field that makes another field mandatory.

I want to be able to:

- Change the border color of the field if it is invalid
- Display a * in front of the field whenever it becomes mandatory
- Display a specific error message that explains what validation rule is broken.

So far, I came up with three solutions but they don't feel so convincing to me.

- Listen to select field changes and update second field's validators.
- Listen to both fields changes and manually perform setErrors
- Lift validation to formGroup (which can feel extremely cumbersome since, validation state is now stored in formGroup and not directly available in formControl).

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-cross-form-validation) implementation that demos my investigations.

Comment: Does it work though?

Comment: All of them do work, but none feels right.
This is why I am asking the community's advice.
By the way, I don't understand why I got downvoted.

Comment: Angular's preferred way to perform cross-validation is to lift validation up (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation), i.e. the third option. Agreed on that it's not quite convenient since the errors are not reflected in the relevant child inputs, however it definitely beats everything else in terms of performance and code complexity.

Answer (score 17):

***UPDATE - ANOTHER APPROACH***
See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77372335/angular-reactive-form-specify-when-to-validate/77373947#77373947)

***UPDATE - A BETTER APPROACH***

Create the `customValidator` over the form and use the validator to use `setError` to the control required. Using `setError`, make that Angular adds `ng-invalid` for us, ad we **needn't** subscribe to value change. See:

```js
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup(
  {
    input1: new FormControl('optional'),
    input2: new FormControl(null),
  },
  { validators: this.customValidatorForm() },
);

customValidatorForm() {
  return (form: FormGroup) => {
    const error =
      form.get('input1').value != 'optional' && !form.get('input2').value
        ? { required: true }
        : null;
    form.get('input2').setErrors(error); //<--see the setErrors
    return error;
  };
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l8d5f9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

***OLD ANSWER***

Just use a `customValidator` like:

```js
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  input1: new FormControl('optional'),
  input2: new FormControl(null, this.customValidator()),
});

customValidator() {
  return (control: any) => {
    if (!control.parent) return null;

    let mandatory = control.parent.get('input1').value;
    return mandatory != 'optional' && !control.value ? { required: true } : null;
  };
}
```

Another option for not ask for `control.parent` it's use `.bind(this)`. This allow us have inside the validator to all the variables of our component, and of course access to `this.form`:

```js
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  input1: new FormControl('optional'),
  input2: new FormControl(null, this.customValidator().bind(this)), //<--bind(this)
});

customValidatorBind() {
  return (control: any) => {
    if (!this.form) return null;

    let mandatory = this.form.get('input1').value;
    return mandatory != 'optional' && !control.value ? { required: true } : null;
  };
}
```

Well, as we want that when change `input1` `input2` was checked, you need use, after create the form subscribe to `valueChanges`:

```js
this.form.get('input1').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  this.form.get('input2').updateValueAndValidity();
});
```

Comment: I have to admit, your solution has one major advantage over replacing Validators. 

It preserves other validators that could exist on the field, whereas replacing validators requires to determine the other validators to keep.

Comment: @Heyjojo, I updated my answer, creating a customValidator over the form and use setError in the validator. I'm sure this aproach like you much more than the others becaouse you don't need susbcribe to values changes

Comment: I don't like this solution however.

1/ The validator gets triggered too many times

2/ It uses formGroup validator to trigger side effects (which is kind of a hack in my opinion).

Comment: You can use {updateOn:'blur'} or { updateOn: 'submit' }, see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#note-on-performance

Comment: Sure I can, but this would also alter the behavior of the formGroup's valueChanges Observable (which wouldn't get triggered). With RXJS, I have more control over when the validations are performed (check my solution with setErrors).

Comment: I changed my mind, I happen to like your last solution better than any other.

Comment: The updated approach is great. We can manually add an error (potentially containing a custom error message if we want by replacing "true" with a string or an object) this way as well as invalidating the exact fields that are invalid (which is important for CSS reasons). Thanks!

Comment: It works great, however it causes `ExpressionChangedAfterItWasInitialized` issue when `SetError` is called.

Comment: @CodeNameJack, Really it's a bit old answer (and I'm not very proud to the result). For me a better approach is in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77372335/angular-reactive-form-specify-when-to-validate/77373947#77373947)

Answer (score 3):

For cross field validation, you can use `required` validation of `@rxweb/reactive-form-validation`.

You just have to mention `conditionalExpression` in your formControl like this:

```
input2:['', RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:'x => x.input1 == "mandatory"' })]
```

and set the error message in your app.component.ts like this

```
ngOnInit(){
    ReactiveFormConfig.set({"validationMessage":{"required":"This field is required"}});
  }
```

Here is your complete component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms"
import { RxwebValidators } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-required-conditionalExpression-validator',
    templateUrl: './required-conditional-expression.component.html'
})
export class RequiredConditionalExpressionValidatorComponent implements OnInit {
    userFormGroup: FormGroup

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder )
    { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            input1:[''], 
            input2:['', RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:'x => x.input1 == "mandatory"' })], 
        });
    }
}
```

Here is your Complete HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="userFormGroup">

        <div>
            <label>Mandatory/Optional </label>
        <select formControlName="input1">
          <option value="optional">Optional</option>
          <option value="mandatory">Mandatory</option>
        </select>
      <br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Input2</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="input2"/><br/>
      <span>
        {{userFormGroup.controls.input2.errors?.required?.message}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pavwsn?file=src/app/required-conditional-expression.component.html)

Comment: I just checked this library's code.
I am really not fan of all this. There is a lot of magic involved. 
Plus it seems, it can only  to go up one formGroup level, which can be restrictive.

Comment: @Heyjojo No problem, this also works with nested formgroup or formarray level as well.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the "better approach" on this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57123631/8126632

I would edit it this way to prevent any other validation to be overwritten:

```
input2: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(4)]),

form.get('input2').setErrors({...error, ...(form.get('input2').errors)});
```

Otherwise a perfect answer.