# Set custom validator with conditionalExpression

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm Angular beginner. How to correctly make a validation with plusValidator only if userType is some value? Is it possible to use conditionalExpression without RxwebValidators?

```
import { plusValidator} from "../../../validators/plus.validator";

@Component({
  templateUrl: "./signup-step-1.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./signup-step-1.component.css"]
})
export class SignupStep1Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  isLoading = false;
  private authStatusSub: Subscription;
  userTypeSelected = '';
  companyForm: FormGroup;
  countries: any = (countries as any).default;
  submitted = false;
  added = false;
  years = [];

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder, public authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.companyForm = this.fb.group({
      trucks: this.fb.array([]),
      companyName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      taxNo: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      dialCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      telephone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      address: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      country: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      postalCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      userType: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
    if(this.userTypeSelected == 'drivers') {
      this.companyForm.get('trucks').setValidators(plusValidator);
      console.log(this.userTypeSelected);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authStatusSub = this.authService.getAuthStatusListener().subscribe(
      authStatus => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    );
    this.years = this.generateArrayOfYears();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.authStatusSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  onSignupStep1() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.added = true;
    this.companyForm.updateValueAndValidity();
    if (this.companyForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.authService.createUserStep1(
      this.companyForm.value.companyName,
      this.companyForm.value.taxNo,
      this.companyForm.value.dialCode,
      this.companyForm.value.telephone,
      this.companyForm.value.address,
      this.companyForm.value.city,
      this.companyForm.value.country,
      this.companyForm.value.postalCode,
      this.companyForm.value.userType,
      2,
      this.companyForm.value.trucks
    );
  }

  onLicPicked(event: Event) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.companyForm.patchValue({ lic: file });
    this.companyForm.get("lic").updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  trucks() : FormArray {
    return this.companyForm.get("trucks") as FormArray
  }

  newTruck(): FormGroup {
    this.added = false;
    return this.fb.group({
      truckModel: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      truckType: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      year: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      regNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      regDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      maxWeight: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      width: new FormControl(),
      height: new FormControl(),
      tlength: new FormControl(),
      hydraulicRamp: new FormControl(),
      crane: new FormControl(),
      winches: new FormControl(),
      adjustableRoof: new FormControl(),
      movableFloor: new FormControl(),
      movableTarpaulin: new FormControl(),
      rotatingSignalLight: new FormControl(),
      containerLifter: new FormControl()

      /*lic: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      })*/
    })
  }

  addTruck() {
    this.trucks().push(this.newTruck());
  }

  removeTruck(i:number) {
    this.trucks().removeAt(i);
  }

  generateArrayOfYears() {
    var max = new Date().getFullYear()
    var min = max - 31
    var years = []

    for (var i = max; i >= min; i--) {
      years.push(i)
    }
    return years
  }
}
```

Using if statement logs this.userTypeSelected correctly but plusValidator doesn't apply for the field. When I put plus validator again to the formControl it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to implement Angular cross field validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120135/best-way-to-implement-angular-cross-field-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setValidators` action to set the validators for a field:

```
if(userType === 'test'){
  const trucksField = this.companyForm.get('trucks');

  trucksField.setValidators([plusValidator]);
  trucksField.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks simple but the plus validator doesn't apply to the field. I have updated question with the whole file

Comment: I updated the example, a call to `updateValueAndValidity` should fix it