# Cross Field Validation: Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My requirement is to validate fields based on the values of other fields. I have 3 fields
slaBeforeExpiry, slaAtExpiry and slaAfterExpiry. Values of these fields should be in ascending order.

slaBeforeExpiry >= slaAtExpiry >= slaAfterExpiry

It works fine when I try to fill the values in order. For example:

If I fill value 2 in slaBeforeExpiry and 3 in slaAtExpiry. Error div appears. and if I change it slaAtExpiry value to less than slaBeforeExpiry error div hides. But if instead of decreasing the value of slaAtExpiry I try increasing the value of slaBeforeExpiry greater than slaAtExpiry error div doesnot go away.

And this happens only for the first time.

here goes my code:

```
<form [formGroup]="slaForm">
<div class="form-group"> 
<label>Sla Before Expiry: </label>
<input autocomplete="off" matInput type="number" min="0" formControlName="slaBeforeExpiry">

</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label>Sla At Expiry: </label>
<input autocomplete="off" type="number" min="0"  matInput formControlName="slaAtExpiry">
<div class="error" *ngIf="slaForm.controls.slaAtExpiry.hasError('slaatexpiry') || slaForm.controls.slaBeforeExpiry.hasError('slaatexpiry')">SLA On Breach should be less than or equal to SLA Before Breach</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label>Sla After Expiry: </label>
<input autocomplete="off" type="number" min="0"  matInput formControlName="slaAfterExpiry">
<div class="error" *ngIf="slaForm.controls.slaAfterExpiry.hasError('slaafterexpiry')
 || slaForm.controls.slaAtExpiry.hasError('slaafterexpiry')">SLA After Breach should be less than or equal to SLA On Breach</div>
</div>

</form>
```

******** ts ********

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ValidatorFn, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  public slaForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup(
    {
      slaBeforeExpiry: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.validateSlaBeforeExpiry]),
      slaAtExpiry: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.validateSlaAtExpiry, this.validateSlaAfterExpiry2]),
      slaAfterExpiry: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.validateSlaAfterExpiry])
    }
  );

  public validateSlaBeforeExpiry (control: FormControl) :ValidatorFn{
    let isValid = null;
    if(control.value !== '' && control.parent.controls['slaAtExpiry'].value !== ''){
      if(control.value >= control.parent.controls['slaAtExpiry'].value ){
        isValid = null;
      }else{
        isValid = {'slaatexpiry': true}
      }
    }
    return isValid;
  }

/**
 * this method validates sla value before expiry is 
 * greater than or equal to sla at expiry
 * @param control 
 * @returns error
 */
 public validateSlaAtExpiry(control: FormControl):ValidatorFn{
  let isValid = null;
  if(control.value !== '' && control.parent.controls['slaBeforeExpiry'].value !== ''){
    if(control.parent.controls['slaBeforeExpiry'].value >= control.value){
      isValid = null;
    }else{
      isValid = {'slaatexpiry': true}
    }
  }
  return isValid;
}

/**
 * this method validates sla after expiry is less than
 * or equal to sla on expiry
 * @param control 
 * @returns error if 
 */
public validateSlaAfterExpiry(control: FormControl):ValidatorFn{
  let isValid = null;
  if(control.value !== '' && control.parent.controls['slaAtExpiry'].value !== ''){
    if(control.parent.controls['slaAtExpiry'].value >= control.value){
      isValid = null;
    }else{
      isValid = {'slaafterexpiry': true}
    }
  }
  return isValid;
}

public validateSlaAfterExpiry2(control: FormControl):ValidatorFn{
  let isValid = null;
  if(control.value !== '' && control.parent.controls['slaAfterExpiry'].value !== ''){
    if(control.value >= control.parent.controls['slaAfterExpiry'].value ){
      isValid = null;
    }else{
      isValid = {'slaafterexpiry': true}
    }
  }
  return isValid;
}
}
```

Looks like I am doing something wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Stackblitz for the same: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vzau71?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Rather than a validator on each control I suggest validator on the formgroup. You can setErrors on the individual controls as needed [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57123631/4711754)

Answer (score 2):

Posting answer if someone faces this issue:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ValidatorFn, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  public slaForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup(
    {
      slaBeforeExpiry: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      slaAtExpiry: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      slaAfterExpiry: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    },{ validators: this.customValidatorForm() },
  );



public customValidatorForm(){
    return ((form:FormGroup)=>{
      let slaBeforeExpiry = form.get('slaBeforeExpiry').value;
      let slaAtExpiry = form.get('slaAtExpiry').value;
      let slaAfterExpiry = form.get('slaAfterExpiry').value;
      let error: any;
      if(slaBeforeExpiry < slaAtExpiry){
        error = {'slaatexpiry': true};
        form.get('slaAtExpiry').setErrors(error);        
      }else{
        form.get('slaAtExpiry').setErrors(error)
      }
      if(slaAtExpiry < slaAfterExpiry){
        error = {'slaafterexpiry': true};
        form.get('slaAfterExpiry').setErrors(error)
      }else{
        form.get('slaAfterExpiry').setErrors(null)
      }              
      return error;
    })
  }      
}
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gd5uum?file=src/app/app.component.ts