# How to know which field has fired cross-validation in FormGroup Validator

Tags: angular, angular-forms, formgroups, angular-custom-validators

My answer is about cross field validation in Angular Form (check the documentation here [cross-field-validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation)).
I would like to know how to find which field's change has fired the form validator when I am inside the validator function (checkAnno, in the example below).
This is my code

```
ngOnInit() {
this.elaborazioneForm = new FormGroup({
  anno: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  modello: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  tipo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  nProtocollo: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true })
},
  {validators: this.checkAnno()}
);
}


checkAnno(): ValidatorFn {
return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
  if (
    !!formGroup.get('anno').value &&
    !!formGroup.get('modello').value &&
    Math.abs(parseInt(formGroup.get('modello').value, 10) - parseInt(formGroup.get('anno').value, 10)) >= 2
  ) {
```

> here I would like to know which is the control that, with its change, has activated the validation of the form

```
    formGroup.controls['anno'].setErrors({twoYearsOrMore: true});
    formGroup.controls['modello'].setErrors({twoYearsOrMore: true});
    return { twoYearsOrMore: true };
  } else {
    formGroup.controls['anno'].setErrors(null);
    formGroup.controls['modello'].setErrors(null);
    return null;
  }
};
```

}

Do you have any ideas how to reach the goal?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? The form is either valid or not and you have access to set errors on individual controls based on the form state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andrew. Because I would like to know which is the control that I have to put in error. In my example, I put in error both of them.

Comment: Ok but *why* do you need to know which is the control that you have to put in error

Comment: _Because_ I would like to put a <mat-error> element under the field responsible for the change which triggered the validator. I would like to highlight the component responsible for the error, and don't set the error on all fields involved in cross-validation. I hope I was clearer

Comment: Pretty sure the question (not answer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74291949/4711754) adapted to your use case should work. i.e. put custom validator on each control (so 2 validators) which will run on value changes.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I think that I'll do something like that. I was curious to know if there was a chance to do so with a formGroup custom validator

Comment: Update: no, it's impossible to reach the goal with two custom control validators. Because when I would check the value of the 'other' control (not the control that triggered the specific validator), the formGroup is still undefined. So the only thing it's to use the formGroup Custom Validator! 
In my case I decided to use thiw workaround: I put the errors on both formControls, than, when I'll close the datapicker I set the other control untouched, and I'll show the <mat-error> only when a control has error && is touched. Not the best elegant solution, but it works!

Comment: Far from perfect but I've got something along the correct lines here https://stackblitz.com/edit/control-validation-accessing-parent?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Perhaps you can clean up and post as answer if it works out? I'm sure the repeated logic can be cleaned up immeasureably

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know how to check which field is valid or invalid you can use this

```
this.form.get('field').invalid
```

Or this for valid

```
this.form.get('field').valid
```

It will work too

```
this.form.controls.field.invalid
```

Comment: I don't want to check if a control is valid/invalid, I would like to figure out which control has determined the entry into function checkAnno(), in order to understand which control to set as invalid (via setError())